# Does MongoClient maintain its collection objects until destroyed? (Python)

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a simple Python MongoClient class and a fetch method from one of its collections.
Let's suppose we have self.db as our default Database.

My first question is, whether pymongo maintains its collection objects until the client object is destroyed.

```py
class MyMongo(MongoClient):
...
    def find_all(self, col_name):
        collection = self.db[col_name]       # here, does it fetch the collection from MongoDB
                                             # everytime?
        return collection.find({})
...
```

Second question is, if I instantiate new Collection instance that points to one of collections in MongoClient above, will I have two Collection instances for the same Collection?

```py
from pymongo.collection import Collection

mongo = MyMongo()
col = Collection(mongo.db, col_name)      # here, will I have two Collection instances?
                                          # for one is inside of mongo (=mongo.db[col_name])
                                          # for another is 'col' variable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collection objects generally only have simple attributes like the name of the collection and options in them. Therefore they are similar to the vast majority of Python objects that any Python application uses, they do not occupy much resources and they will be garbage collected when they are no longer referenced.